# Present new ViewController after Interstitial Ad is closed - Swift 4

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, admob, segue, interstitial

I am trying to make this button segue to a new ViewController once the user closes the interstitial ad. The segue code works without the ad code and the ad code works without the segue code. Whichever one is put first happens first, but I can't figure out how to get them to work together. You'll notice that I tried moving `self.present...` to various places with no success (see noted out lines).

```
@IBAction func adButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let myVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "newVC")
    //self.present(myVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

    if (interstitial.isReady) {
        interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
        interstitial = createAd()
        //self.present(myVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    self.present(myVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `interstitial` object has a delegate (`GADInterstitialDelegate`) protocol that you can conform to in order to be notified when the ad has been dismissed. There are several delegate methods addressing the ad state which you can review in the documentation.

```
class ViewController:UIViewController, GADInterstitialDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")
        interstitial.delegate = self
        let request = GADRequest()
        interstitial.load(request)
    }

    @IBAction func adButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if (interstitial.isReady) {
            interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
        } else {
           self.present(myVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
       }
    }

    //Tells the delegate the interstitial is to be animated off the screen.
    func interstitialWillDismissScreen(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {
        print("interstitialWillDismissScreen")
    }

    //Tells the delegate the interstitial had been animated off the screen.
    func interstitialDidDismissScreen(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {
        print("interstitialDidDismissScreen")
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let myVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "newVC")
        self.present(myVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Google Ads Docs: [Interstitial Ads](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/interstitial)

Comment: I tried the second func example earlier with no success. Inside of it I placed a segue to the new ViewController, but it did not work. Do those functions need to be called somewhere else in the code or do they just need to be created?

Comment: They would be part of whatever object is conforming to the  `GADInterstitialDelegate` protocol, often this is the view controller presenting the ad.

Comment: I put func interstitialDidDismissScreen ... at the bottom of the VC in which I created the Interstitial Ad, but I couldn’t even get the print statement. And I know the rest of my code works because I can either show Interstitial Test Ad or segue to the new VC. I just still can’t figure out how to do both.

Comment: I updated the sample code to show conforming to the protocol. You need to make sure you set the view controller as the delegate of the ad you create. I would try just getting the delegate methods for the ad to work. Once those methods get called you should be able to present your own view controller when the ad is dismissed.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate your follow up. I just saw your edit and I’ll give that a try. One potential issue that I should have mentioned earlier is that I have four different buttons that lead to four different new VC’s depending on which one the user chooses to press. Based on your answer, there is only one option for the new VC. Should I try a switch statement to address that or is there a more efficient way?

Comment: I was just trying to illustrate how to be notified when the ad is dismissed. The `interstitial` ads use delegation, so only the delegate of the `interstitial` ad will be notified that the ad was dismissed. In that method you would have to decide which view controller to present.

Comment: I wasn’t setting the ViewController as the Delegate of the ad. That explains why it wasn’t printing for me.

Comment: Nice Solution! Thanks!

Comment: Hi, this solution works great. Thank you so much! But it is possible to update for the new google admob SDK (2021)?, I am trying to update on my apps but it doesn't work. Thank you.